# ASP.NET GridView Response.BinaryWrite() On Row Change

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, gridview, updatepanel

I have a gridview inside of an updatepanel and would like to allow the user to select a row which would generate a call to a class that outputs a stream back to the client.  It looks like I can't do this because the grid is inside of an update panel.  Any ideas?

C#

```
    protected void gvResults_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RMATagsReport rpt = new RMATagsReport();
        rpt.GenerateReport();
    }
```

ASP.NET

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upResults" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:GridView ID="gvResults" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4"
        ForeColor="#333333" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvResults_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="100%">
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CSTNO" HeaderText="DEALER" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ORDNO" HeaderText="RMA NUMBER" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CSTORD" HeaderText="DEALER PO NUMBER" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ORDDTE" HeaderText="ORDER DATE" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="INVDTE" HeaderText="INVOICE DATE" HtmlEncode="false" />
            <asp:CommandField SelectText="Print RMA" ShowSelectButton="True" />
        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#3494CC" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            <span style="color: Red;">No RMA Tags Found With Specified Criteria. </span>
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
    </asp:GridView>
    <div id="LoadingDiv" style="display: none; text-align: center;">
        <img src="Graphics/Icons/loading_lg.gif" />
    </div>
    <div id="ResultsDiv">
    </div>
</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSearch" EventName="Click" />
</Triggers>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm doing a response.redirect on the index change now with the new page handling the report generation...  This seems to work OK.

**EDIT**
While this seems to work, I am still open to other possibilities as I don't want to have a page that's only purpose is to output this document.